# 1C 8.3. Как получить ссылку обработки?

Tags: 1с

1C 8.3. Как получить ссылку "Обработки"?

Comment: Уточните, какой именно, внешней либо встроенной?

Comment: @kio Встроенной

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У обработки нет ссылки в классическом понимании. Если требуется доступ к методам из модуля обработки, то можно использовать **МенеджерОбработки**:

> **ОбработкаМенеджер**.<Имя обработки> (DataProcessorManager.<Имя обработки>)
>
> Синтаксис:
>
> **Создать()**
> Возвращаемое значение:
>
> **Тип:** ОбработкаОбъект.<Имя обработки>.
>
> **Описание:**
> Создает новый экземпляр обработки.
>
> **Доступность:**
> Сервер, толстый клиент, внешнее соединение, мобильное приложение(сервер).
>
> **Пример:**
> ОбработкаДокументов = Обработки.ОбработкаДокументов.Создать();

Если же вам требуется получить перечень обработок зарегистрированных в системе, проверить наличие определенной либо получить доступ к внутренним параметрам используйте **Метаданные**:

> ОбъектМетаданныхКонфигурация (ConfigurationMetadataObject)
> **Использование:**
> Только чтение.
>
> **Описание:**
> **Тип:** КоллекцияОбъектовМетаданных.
> Коллекция объектов метаданных, которые описывают все обработки, определенные в конфигурации.
> Элементами коллекции являются объекты типа ОбъектМетаданных: Обработка.
>
> **Доступность:**
> Сервер, толстый клиент, внешнее соединение, мобильное приложение(сервер).